# Need suggestions on using Entrust roles in a single resource controller - Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5, acl, user-roles

I am working on a control panel app where i have several user roles like globaladmin, editors etc. Now i want to use these roles with a single UserController Resource.

For example globaladmins should be able to perform all Restful methods, while an editor can only View and Update a user.

**I know that entrust comes with middlewares out of the box, which is perfect for what i need. But it works on the routes only (in which case i would need separate controller for each role)** .

My UserController looks something like this.

```
Class UserController extends BaseController
{
     $protected $viewfolder;
     public function __construct
     {
        // Checking for role and then assigning the folder name of the views
        $role = User::getRole();
        switch($role)
        case 'globaladmin':
              $this->viewfolder = 'globaladmin';
              break;
        case 'editor':
              $this->viewfolder = 'editor';
              break;
        default:
              abort(401, 'Access Denied');
              break;
     }

     public function index(){
        if( Entrust::can('view-all-users') ){
            $users = User:all();
        }
        return view( $this->viewfolder.'.users.viewuser', compact('users'));
     }
     public function create()
     public function update()
     public function delete()
}
```

**I need a middleware in the constructor that would check for user role and then only allow to use the method only if the role has permission to use it. But this should be done in a decent way without any hacks because i will be using it on other controllers as well.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are using the following in your routes file:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

In this case, I would suggest, that you use one of the middlewares provided by Entrust as base and retrieve the called method, e.g. if you use EntrustRole:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $controllerMethod = Route::segment(3);
    $roles = $this->retrieveRequiredRolesForMethod($method);
    if ($this->auth->guest() || !$request->user()->hasRole(explode('|', $roles))) {
        abort(403);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Of course this is just a hint and you should find a better way to extract the called method and still need to implement `retrieveRequiredRolesForMethod`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although i have went down another route of having individual controller for each role, because of the complexity of the app. But i really like this idea. Lets wait and see if someone come up with a new perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. I think this will work in your case.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {                        
        $this->middleware('permission:user_index', ['only' => ['index']]); 
        $this->middleware('permission:user_create', ['only' => ['create', 'store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:user_edit', ['only' => ['edit', 'update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:user_delete', ['only' => ['delete']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:user_view', ['only' => ['show']]);            

    }
}
```

Here user_index,user_create, user_edit etc are the permissions(entries in permission table name field) for user module.

This will automatically check the logged-in user ability and will show page accordingly.